# iOS10 UIImagePickerController embedded as ChildViewController, not showing its subviews correctly

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

I am using an UIImagePickerController embedded in a square view container.  It worked fine on iOS 8 and 9.  On iOS 10, the internal objects of the UIImagePickerController will not stretch to the full width of the camera picker controller.  See 2 screenshots: 
[image]

[image]

The selected view in the view inspector is: CAMPreviewView  (inside UIImagePickerController).

Here is the code I use for embedding the UIImagePickerController as a subview:

```
- (void) presentCameraInWindow {
[self addChildViewController:self.videoRecorder];

[self.cameraHolder
    addControls:@[self.videoRecorder.view]
    align:VerticalAlignStretchToFullHeight
    withHeight:self.view.bounds.size.width
    verticalPadding: 0.0f
    horizontalPadding:0.0f];

[[self.videoRecorder view] setNeedsLayout];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.videoRecorder didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

NOTE: addControls is a vertical Layout engine i built which I use everywhere.  It creates constraints automatically, programmatically, so i don't have to.

I call this set up in viewDidLoad.

The same issue occurs, if i don't use Constraints, and I set the frame of the UIImagePickerController manually.

We can clearly see in the view inspector that the UIImagePickerController is laying out correctly (to the full width and height of the container view, but it's internal subviews are not).

Also:  Using AVFoundation directly is not an option right now, because of the effort involved.

Comment: I found a workaround.  I now add the UIImagePickerController to the self.view of the parent view controller.   This issue was only happening when I tried to add it to a smaller view.  Something constraint-based inside image picker breaks when you try to house it in a view that is smaller than its own frame.  In other words: it wants to be full screen.  So i added it to self.view, and then moved it to the position I wanted it to be: (shifted up by (screen height - screen width) / 2.0), then i covered it with overlay views, by sending it to back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to embed the UIImagePickerController in a subview that had a smaller frame than that of the Parent View Controller.  So I embedded the UIImagePickerController in the self.view of the View controller housing it.  Then I sent it to back, putting overlays on top of it as needed.  I also ended up moving up its frame by a certain amount, since my app works with square videos.  So it doesn't mind if I move its frame partly outside of the visible screen coordinates, as long as I don't try squishing its frame smaller than the size it wants to be.  If I do that, then the internal viewfinder subviews inside UIImagePickerController start to lay-out unexpectedly (cut off).  Again, this issue occurs on iOS10 only.